# Porque é que temos o "c com cedilha"? (Why do we have "c with cedilla"?)

Tags: ortografia, pronúncia, fonemas, mudanças-históricas

A letra *ç* é usada em algumas palavras, mas tem o mesmo som que o grupo *ss*. Não seria mais simples se todas as palavras com este som se escrevessem com *ss*?

Suponho que o motivo seja que a raíz da palavra se escrevia com *ç*, e que em algum ponto tivesse uma pronúncia diferente, mas este não me parece um bom motivo para o manter. Há algum motivo, para além de "backwards compatibility" para usar esta letra?

---

The letter *ç* (c with cedilla) is used in some words, but makes the same sound as *ss*. Wouldn't it be simpler if every word with this sound were written with *ss*?

I suppose the reason is that at its root, the word would have been written with *ç*, and at some point it would have a different pronunciation, but this does not sound like a good reason to keep it. Is there a good reason for this, aside from keeping "backwards compatibility"?

Comment: Boa pergunta, o português é cheio de complicações, como o porquê do "s" no meio de uma palavra tem som de "z", mas se for precedido de uma consoante então tem som de "s" e etc....

Comment: "S" tem som de "z" se estiver entre duas vogais. Simples assim. Por que as pessoas acham que português é tão complicado assim?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Porque _é_. _Qua_ lê-se como _cua_, mas _que_ não se lê como _cue_. Excepções criam complicações.

Comment: @someonewithpc o português nasceu assim com exceções, não é assim tão complicado de aprender. Poderíamos inventar outra língua sem exceções, que achas?

Comment: @JorgeB. Podíamos, mas acabarías com algo como Esperanto ou Lojban

Comment: Seria mais simples. Mas o português, assim como outras línguas, não é mantido/teorizado por cientistas que gostam de elegância e coerência. É mantido/teorizado por idiotas que preferem manter ou inserir diferenças baseadas no feeling de beleza poética e histórica que eles tem. Pra eles, sua questão não faz nenhum sentido, já que blá-blá-blá histórico deve ser preservado. Se você quiser algo sofisticado e poderoso onde tais frescuras não existem, estude linguagens formais.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Português

Existem duas formas distintas de escrever o fonema /s/ hoje porque a nossa ortografia moderna **não reflete a pronúncia atual**, mas sim a pronúncia do **português *arcaico***.

A letra *ç* tem origem no castelhano antigo. Naquela época ainda se escreviam as palavras da mesma forma que elas continuam a ser escritas no português moderno.

Existiam seis sibilantes distintas, cada uma escrita com a sua própria letra ou letras.  Este sistema ortográfico é preservado no português de hoje, embora os sons separados há muito tempo se tenham mesclado, e a distinção original perdida.

De [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_das_sibilantes_do_castelhano):

> Entre as consoantes do castelhano antigo falado aproximadamente até o início do século XIII, encontravam-se os seguintes pares de sibilantes, surdas e sonoras, com valor de distinção fonológica:
>
> - Duas africadas alveolares, surda e sonora: **/ʦ/** e /ʣ/ (como o *z* do italiano, ou da palavra *pizza*), representadas pelas grafias ***ç*** (*c* ante i/e) e *z*, **exatamente igual ao português arcaico**;
> - Duas fricativas apicoalveolares, surda e sonora: /s/ e /z/, representadas pelo *s* no início de sílabas e final de palavras ou por *ss* para /s/ e *s* para /z/ entre vogais, como no português moderno;
> - Duas fricativas pós-alveolares, surda e sonora: /ʃ/ (como o nosso *ch* ou *x*) e /ʒ/ (como o nosso *j*), representadas por *x* e *j* (*g* antes de *e*, *i*), como no português moderno.

No [artigo de Wikipedia sobre a letra *ç*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87), lemos:

> Ç foi usado inicialmente para simbolizar a africada alveolar surda /t͡s/ no espanhol medieval e se origina da forma da letra "z" na [escrita visigótica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escrita_visig%C3%B3tica). Esse fonema teve origem no latim vulgar a partir da palatalização das consoantes plosivas /t/ e /k/ em determinadas condições. Posteriormente, /t͡s/ converteu-se em /s/ em várias línguas românicas e dialetos.
> [image: Evolução do Z (Ꝣ) visigótico ao moderno Ç.]
>
> #### *Evolução do Z (Ꝣ) visigótico ao moderno Ç*

Por isso, era originalmente um *c* sentado em cima da letra *z*, ou com *z* conectado embaixo.

---

### English

There are two different ways of writing the phoneme /s/ today because our modern spelling **does not reflect current pronunciation**, but rather the pronunciation of ***archaic* Portuguese**.

The letter *ç* originated in Old Spanish. During that time words were written in the same way as they’re still written in Modern Portuguese.

There were six different sibilants, each written with its own letter or letters. This system of spelling is preserved in today’s Portuguese, even though the separate sounds long ago got merged together and the original distinction lost.

From Wikipedia (in translation):

> > Among the consonants of Old Spanish spoken up until around the beginning of the 17th century were the following pairs of sibilants, unvoiced and voiced, with distinct phonologic values:
> >
> > - Two alveolar affricates, unvoiced and voiced:   **/ʦ/** e /ʣ/ (like the Italian *z*, or in the word *pizza*), represented by the spellings *ç* (*c* before *i* or *e*) and *z*, exactly the same as Old Portuguese.
> > - Two apicoalveolar fricatives, unvoiced and voiced: /s/ and /z/, represented by *s* at the start of a syllable or by *ss* for /s/ and *s* for /z/ between vowels, as in Modern Portuguese.
> > - Two postalveolar fricatives, unvoiced and voiced: /ʃ/ (like our *ch* or *x*) and /ʒ/ (like our *j*), represented by *x* and *j* (*g* before *e* or *i*), as in Modern Portuguese.

In the Wikipedia article on the letter *ç*, we read (in translation):

> > At first the symbol *ç* was used for the unvoiced alveolar affricate  /t͡s/  in Medieval Spanish and had its origins in the letter *z* in Visigothic writing.  That phoneme had its origin in Vulgar Latin following the palatalization of the consonant stops /t/ and /k/ in particular conditions.  Afterwards, /t͡s/  became /s/ in various Romance languages and dialects.
> >
> > [image: Evolution of Visigothic Z (Ꝣ) to modern Ç]
> >
> > #### *Evolution of Visigothic Z (Ꝣ) to modern Ç*

So it was originally a *c* seated atop the letter *z*, or with a *z* connected below.

Comment: +1 Só de ler a primeira frase.

Comment: Muito interesante. E então por isso que *ç* muitas vezes vira *z* quando escrito em espanhol e inglês? (E as vez até francês, no caso de Moçambique.)

Comment: @DanGetz Sí, la vieja *ç* castellana del *Cantar de mio **Ç**id* se convirtió en una *z* en el idioma actual.  // Sim, o velho *ç* castelhano do *Cantar de mio **Ç**id*  converteu-se num *z* no idioma actual.  // Yes, the old Castilian *ç* from the *Cantar de mio **Ç**id* became a *z* in the current language.

Comment: Se me lembro bem, no norte de Portugal ainda há regiões que distinguem entre S/Z/Ç (o S é pronunciado apicalmente, seja soante ou não; o Ç e o Z são pronunciados sem a qualidade apical, soante no caso de Z e surdo com o Ç)

Answer (score 8):

Para corrigir a grafia de várias palavras em que o *"c"* não se justifica. Era o *"c"* em latim sempre pronunciado como *"k"*:

- Cícero, Kíkero;
- Díscere, dískere.

Na decadência do latim, e, conseguintemente, na formação das línguas neolatinas, o som de gutural explosiva forte continuou antes de *"a"*, *"o"*, *"u"*:

- Caro
- Corpo
- Culpa

Mas abrandou-se antes das vogais *"e"* e *"i"*, como também antes de *"a"*, *"o"*, *"u"* quando acrescido da *"cedilha"* (cedilha é a forma diminutiva vernácula do espanhol *"ceda"*, a qual é hoje representada por um pequeno *"c"* virado para trás que se sotopõe ao *"c"* que então se denomina **"cê cedilhado"** ou **"cê cedilha"**).

Comment: E não poderia ser substituído por _ss_?

Comment: @ANeves ajustei

Comment: @someonewithpc poderia. Poderíamos uniformizar a língua, mas perderíamos a forma original. Porquê alterar o que funciona?

Comment: @JorgeB. As línguas evoluem naturalmente. Talvez seja este o futuro do português, mas provavelmente não; entretanto o único que posso fazer é chamar à atenção para os problemas, e ver se se resolvem.

Comment: Realmente, o português tem muitas regras, acredito que deva ser bem complicado aprender pra quem não é nativo.

Comment: É sim Lucas, mas para tornar o português mais simples mais vale começarmos a falar Inglês. @someonewithpc eu acho que isso não são problemas. São regras que fazem parte da nossa língua. Que eu por acaso adoro, e que quero que se mantenha como está. O caso de, em Portugal, se terem tirado os as consoantes mudas acho bem como "contacto" e "artefacto". Essas não estão lá mesmo a fazer nada.

Comment: @JorgeB. E deixa o português de Portugal mais próximo com o do Brasil

Comment: @JorgeB De fato, com os meus amigos eu _falo_ inglês a maioria do tempo :P Repara que eu nunca disse que era um problema, é apenas um _pet peeve_ meu.

Comment: @someonewithpc "...o único que posso fazer é chamar à atenção para os **problemas**, e ver se se resolvem..." ;)

Comment: É um pet peeve :P

Comment: Tá certo que o português europeu se aproximou da variante falada no Brasil, mas nós, brasileiros, tivemos também que alterar demais a nossa ortografia a fim de ficar lado a lado com a vossa gramática, e isto eu não gostei por nada. Muitas destas mudanças eu nem as considero quando escrevo meus textos e peço todos os dias a Deus que me livre de fazer algum exame escolar e ser reprovado por coisas que eu não julgo erradas. Até as idiotas das editoras de jornais, livros e revistas aderiram à loucura destas novas regras gramaticais, quer sejam escolares quer não.

Answer (score 1):

Por motivos etimologicos.

Por exemplo a palavra *espaço*, poderia grafar-se *espasso*, mas isso afastá-la-ia de outras linguas, como o espanhol *espacio*, o inglês *space*, etc.

Se fossemos por essas simplificações, poderiamos substituir todos os S com som de Z por Z (caza, fraze, quaze), e então substituir todos os SS e todos os C com som de S por S (pasado, senario, calsado, braso). Então, poderiamos substituir todos os QU com som de C por C (atace, bosce, cerer).

O mesmo poderia ser aplicado ao G com som de J, passando a J (jente, jeral, jelado), e os GU com som de G poderiam ser substituidos por G (gerreiro, figeiral, fogete).

Então teriamos uma grafia muito mais simples mas também um bocado mais escizita.

Comment: Concordo que seria estranho, mas do por estar habituado à grafia atual. Mas, mais importante, discordo que se poderia substituir 'qu' por 'c'; 'k' seria uma melhor escolha, para evitar as ambiguidades do 'c'.

Comment: @someonewithpc o c deixaria de ter ambiguidade passando a representar sempre o som /k/, tal como o g iria representar sempre o som /g/.
Por isso teriamos: gerreiro, figeiral, fogete, sinema, cerer, etc.